System of 4 equations with 4 unknowns in Excel: stress and strain evolution during temperature cycles (hysteresis loop)
I am trying to solve the following system of $4$ equations with $4$ unknowns (in red):
$$\begin{cases}
\color{red}{\gamma_{iv}} + \frac{\color{red}{\tau_{iv}}}{1372} = 4.24 \times 10^{-4} (T_{i + 1} -30) \\
\color{red}{\gamma_{i + 1}} + \frac{\color{red}{\tau_{i + 1}}}{1372} = 4.24 \times 10^{-4} (T_{i + 1} - 30) \\
\color{red}{\gamma_{iv}} - \gamma_i = \frac{2 \tau_i (\color{red}{\tau_{iv}} - \tau_i)}{\tau_p^2} \\
\color{red}{\gamma_{i + 1}} - \color{red}{\gamma_{iv}} = 120 \left[ 8.31 \color{red}{\tau_{iv}} |\color{red}{\tau_{iv}}| \exp \left( -\frac{0.5}{8.6 \times 10^{-5} (T_{i + 1} + 273.15)} \right) + 1.12 \color{red}{\tau_{iv}} |\color{red}{\tau_{iv}}|^{6.1} \exp \left( -\frac{0.84}{8.6 \times 10^{-5} (T_{i + 1} + 273.15)} \right) \right]
\end{cases}$$
With $\gamma_i$ and $\tau_i$  the initial values of the iterative process (both $0$). The parameter $\tau_p$ depends on the temperature:
$$\tau_p = \tau_p (T_i) = 0.00689475908677536 (49367 - (299 T_i))$$
The temperature cycle  begins at $T_0 = 31^\circ {\rm C}$ (with $\gamma_0 = 0$ and $\tau_0 = 0$), then increases to $125^\circ {\rm C}$, then decreases to $-25^\circ {\rm C}$ and increase again until reaching $30^\circ {\rm C}$. With $T_{i + 1} - T_i = 1^\circ {\rm C}$.
So the resolution is made every $1^\circ {\rm C}$ (first $31^\circ {\rm C}$, then $32^\circ {\rm C}$, etc.), the solver does it very well between $31^\circ {\rm C}$ to $125^\circ {\rm C}$ but when temperature decreases, the resolution does not work anymore (it seems to work for the $\gamma_i$ values but not the $\gamma_i$ which become $0$).
The violet curve is what I am suppose to get and the orange one is what I get with my system of equations:
Stress vs. strain
Here is the Excel file with the macro allowing the calculations of the $\gamma_i$ and $\tau_i$:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SCKE-uWkO4MUOrKkvZhUbdJfChYhREIb/view?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance for your help :)
JB

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

I have tried to format your equations for ease of viewing. Please check that they match the original problem.

The equation (3) in the original link is missing the $\frac{\tau_{iv} - \tau_i}{G}$ term that is found in the spreadsheet - is this purposeful?

Hello K. Jiang, thank you for your answer. Yes I remove this term it's not the troublesome one.
